# make nginx redirect to random port

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, load-balancing

I'm working on setting up a load balancer for my website. I want to do it manually so that I have full control over how the requests are rerouted. Im using AWS EBS to load balance between 2 ec2 instances, and that works fine. Each ec2 instance uses nginx as a reverse proxy for nodejs.

Currently, I only have 1 node app running on each server, but Ideally I would like to have 4 node apps on each server (1 for each core).

I was thinking that a really easy way to manage this would be to allow nginx to pick a random port between 8081, and 8084 and redirect to one of the apps. In theory this way I would be balancing the load as evenly as possible.

Currently this is my nginx reverse proxy set up:

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 200M;
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        client_max_body_size 200M;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Real-User-Agent $http_user_agent;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header X-serv-ip 'my.server.ip';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

Basically, my question boils down to if there's some way to make a variable like $rand_port and every time a request is made, $rand_port is set to 8081, 8082, 8083, or 8084, and then in my proxy_pass I could do something like:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:{$rand_port} #not sure if the syntax is right.
```

Is there anything that lets me do something like this, or otherwise what other solutions are there?

Comment: Have you tried [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/). It can spin up same number of node servers as the number of cores you have (or less if you want that). This way, your nginx just needs just one port mapping and rest all mapping is done by PM2.

Answer (score 1):

[nginx load balancing](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html)  allows you to determine the algorithm ... if you just need each server to be equally loaded use this

```
    upstream myproject {
        server 127.0.0.1:8081;
        server 127.0.0.1:8082;
        server 127.0.0.1:8083;
        server 127.0.0.1:8084;
    }

    server {
        client_max_body_size 200M;
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name _;

        location / {
            client_max_body_size 200M;
            proxy_pass http://myproject;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Real-User-Agent $http_user_agent;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header X-serv-ip 'my.server.ip';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for answering. I tried this and ran into 2 problems:
1. I tried putting this into my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file but it gives me an error that the http directive is not allowed here. 
2. I then got rid of the http directive, and tried it but my site was not responding. however I gave it about a minute and tried again and it seems to work. I think it might be that after restarting nginx it takes it several seconds to configure the upstream servers? Regardless, it works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: it should be in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` file, given that it is not symlinked.